# Which language to choose for mobile Application(Kotlin or Flutter)

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I am new to mobile app development, please provide me your valuable suggestions

Should I learn Kotlin or Flutter?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here, see the [help].

Comment: Start with both and decide for yourself which you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends.. Kotlin is quite Android specific. If you want to develop cross-plattform apps, I would recommend Flutter. However, if you want to use native features like camera, sensors etc. I could imagine that you are better off with Kotlin and Android.